# autocomplete works only with spaces

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, autocomplete, typeahead.js

From the following jQuery code I have initialized the typeahead plugin

```
var users=new Bloodhound({

    datumTokenizer:Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('username'),
    queryTokenizer:Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,

    remote: {
        url: 'users.php?query=%QUERY',
        wildcard: '%QUERY'
      }

});

users.initialize();

$("#SearchCustomer").typeahead({
    hint: true,
    highlight: true,
    minlength: 2,



},{
    name: 'users',
    display:'username',     
    source:users.ttAdapter(),
    templates: {
        suggestion: function (users) {
        return '<p><a href="index.php?userid='+users.CustomerId+'" style="color:inherit;text-decoration:none;width:100%">'+users.username+'</a></p>';
        }
    }
```

For instance my database is like this:

1.Harley 
2.Harley Davidson

When I type "Har" in then search box, "Harley" is only shown in the suggestions. "Harley Davidson" is shown only when I type "Harley" with a space at the end. Can someone please suggest how to overcome this mistake?

This is my users.php file

```
<?php

header('Content-Type:application/json');

if(!isset($_GET['query']))
{
echo json_encode([]);
exit();
}
$mysqli=new PDO("mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=website","root","");

$users=$mysqli->prepare("SELECT id,username FROM users WHERE username LIKE         :query");

$users->execute(['query'=>"{$_GET['query']}%"]);

echo json_encode($users->fetchAll()); 
?>
```

Comment: Can we see the users.php code where the database query is taking place? Have you debugged the PHP code to make sure that what's being typed into the search box is what's being included in the query?

Comment: @Cᴏʀʏ i have modified the question and included the users.php file

Comment: What does the data look like that gets returned from the url?  If you use a tool like POSTMan to call the url, does it work?

Answer (score 1):

try to capitalize first character of each word by doing this your issue will get cleared

Change harley Davidson To Harley Davidson. Repeat the same for every instance in the table ... regards

Answer (score 0):

I copied your code and add the js files and works. let me show my code

index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="">
</head>
<body>
<input type="text" id="SearchCustomer">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="typeahead.js-master/dist/typeahead.bundle.js"></script>
<script>
    var users=new Bloodhound({

    datumTokenizer:Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('username'),
    queryTokenizer:Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,

    remote: {
        url: 'users.php?query=%QUERY',
        wildcard: '%QUERY'
      }

});

users.initialize();

$("#SearchCustomer").typeahead({
    hint: true,
    highlight: true,
    minlength: 2,



},{
    name: 'users',
    display:'username',     
    source:users.ttAdapter(),
    templates: {
        suggestion: function (users) {
        return '<p><a href="index.php?userid='+users.CustomerId+'" style="color:inherit;text-decoration:none;width:100%">'+users.username+'</a></p>';
        }
    }
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

users.php

```
<?php

header('Content-Type:application/json');

$users = array(
    array( 'CustomerId'=> 'example', 'username'=> 'Harley'),
    array( 'CustomerId'=> 'another example', 'username'=> 'Harley Davidson')
);

echo json_encode($users); 
?>
```

I didn't used Data base, so is possible the data coming from data base is coming with some rubbish.

I hope this can be some help.

Have fun programming!

UPDATE:

I change the users.php, now the JSON don't have rubbish..

```
<?php

header('Content-Type:application/json');

if(!isset($_GET['query']))
{
echo json_encode([]);
exit();
}
$mysqli=new PDO("mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=example","root","");

$users=$mysqli->query("SELECT id,username FROM Users WHERE username LIKE '%".$_GET['query']."%'");


$array = [];
while($row = $users->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $array[] = $row;
}

// echo '<pre>';
// print_r($array);
echo json_encode($array); 

?>
```

Comment: just change "Haryley Davidson" To "harley Davidson" And check the code ... it works fine with upper case but not with lower case